# Plymouth problems for Radeon HD 4850 on 15.04

Tags: boot, ati, plymouth, display-resolution

I have had imperfect behaviour from Plymouth as long as I've had the card - i.e. across several years of Ubuntu versions. Card is connected via Onkyo SR707 receiver to HDTV, using open-source drivers. Two main items:

*No splash*

Graphical splash screen is not shown, TV shows "Mode Not Supported" until desktop login loads. GRUB is in a reasonable resolution (`vbeinfo` says 800x600x32), aubergine blank screen shows momentarily after selected `Ubuntu` from the menu. This goes black instead of showing the splash. Plymouth debug logs show a variety of failures, most look like attempts to probe devices to me. The relevant section appears to be the most successful attempt, on `/dev/fb0`:

```
[ply-device-manager.c:284]                    create_seats_for_subsystem:creating seats for frame buffer devices
[ply-device-manager.c:303]                    create_seats_for_subsystem:found device /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/0000:01:00.0/graphi
cs/fb0
[ply-device-manager.c:311]                    create_seats_for_subsystem:device is initialized
[ply-device-manager.c:322]                    create_seats_for_subsystem:found node /dev/fb0
[ply-device-manager.c:178]                   create_seat_for_udev_device:device is for local console: yes
[ply-device-manager.c:191]                   create_seat_for_udev_device:device subsystem is graphics
[ply-device-manager.c:200]                   create_seat_for_udev_device:found frame buffer device /dev/fb0
[ply-device-manager.c:135]                      fb_device_has_drm_device:trying to find associated drm node for fb device (path: (null))
[ply-device-manager.c:161]                      fb_device_has_drm_device:no card entry!
[ply-device-manager.c:641]    create_seat_for_terminal_and_renderer_type:creating seat for /dev/fb0 (renderer type: 2) (terminal: /dev/tty7)
[ply-renderer.c:234]                      ply_renderer_open_plugin:trying to open renderer plugin /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/plymouth/renderers/fra
me-buffer.so
[./plugin.c:259]                                create_backend:creating renderer backend for device /dev/fb0
[ply-terminal.c:615]                             ply_terminal_open:terminal /dev/tty7 is already open
[./plugin.c:515]                                  query_device:32 bpp (8, 8, 8, 0) with rowstride 5120
[./plugin.c:275]                               initialize_head:initializing 1280x720 head
[ply-renderer.c:256]                      ply_renderer_open_plugin:opened renderer plugin /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/plymouth/renderers/frame-buffe
r.so
[ply-seat.c:80]                            add_pixel_displays:Adding displays for 1 heads
[ply-seat.c:116]                             add_text_displays:adding text display for terminal /dev/tty7
[main.c:1051]                                 on_seat_added:listening for keystrokes
[main.c:1055]                                 on_seat_added:listening for escape
[main.c:1059]                                 on_seat_added:listening for backspace
[main.c:1063]                                 on_seat_added:listening for enter
[ply-device-manager.c:303]                    create_seats_for_subsystem:found device /sys/devices/virtual/graphics/fbcon
[ply-device-manager.c:334]                    create_seats_for_subsystem:it's not initialized
[main.c:2367]                                          main:entering event loop
```

So apparently there is no card entry for the FB device and/or it's not initialized. Eventually I see:

```
[main.c:266]                                 show_messages:not displaying messages, since no boot splash
```

Code here says splash is null, probably due to the earlier failure.

1280x720 is also my desktop resolution and definitely supported, so this seems okay. Splash shows correctly at shutdown.

**EDIT**

Using FB at all is fall-back behaviour according to [the documentation](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/Plymouth/). An earlier attempt fails like this:

```
[ply-device-manager.c:303]                    create_seats_for_subsystem:found device /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/0000:01:00.0/drm/ca
rd0
[ply-device-manager.c:311]                    create_seats_for_subsystem:device is initialized
[ply-device-manager.c:322]                    create_seats_for_subsystem:found node /dev/dri/card0
[ply-device-manager.c:178]                   create_seat_for_udev_device:device is for local console: yes
[ply-device-manager.c:191]                   create_seat_for_udev_device:device subsystem is drm
[ply-device-manager.c:195]                   create_seat_for_udev_device:found DRM device /dev/dri/card0
[ply-device-manager.c:641]    create_seat_for_terminal_and_renderer_type:creating seat for /dev/dri/card0 (renderer type: 1) (terminal: /dev/t
ty7)
[ply-renderer.c:234]                      ply_renderer_open_plugin:trying to open renderer plugin /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/plymouth/renderers/drm
.so
[./plugin.c:379]                                create_backend:creating renderer backend for device /dev/dri/card0
[./plugin.c:464]                                   load_driver:Opening '/dev/dri/card0'
[ply-terminal.c:619]                             ply_terminal_open:trying to open terminal '/dev/tty7'
[ply-terminal.c:409]                 ply_terminal_look_up_geometry:looking up terminal text geometry
[ply-terminal.c:424]                 ply_terminal_look_up_geometry:terminal is now 160x45 text cells
[ply-terminal.c:462]                                 get_active_vt:Remembering that initial vt is 7
[./plugin.c:860]                                  query_device:Could not initialize heads
[ply-renderer.c:250]                      ply_renderer_open_plugin:could not query rendering device for plugin /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/plymouth/
renderers/drm.so
[./plugin.c:552]                                  close_device:closing device
[./plugin.c:501]                                 unload_driver:unloading driver
[ply-renderer.c:288]                             ply_renderer_open:could not find suitable rendering plugin
[ply-seat.c:135]                                 ply_seat_open:could not open renderer for /dev/dri/card0
[ply-device-manager.c:646]    create_seat_for_terminal_and_renderer_type:could not create seat
[ply-seat.c:326]                           free_pixel_displays:freeing 0 pixel displays
[ply-seat.c:348]                            free_text_displays:freeing 0 text displays
```

As far as I'm aware the HD 4000 series has mature DRM/DRI support. `glxinfo` reports `direct rendering: Yes`.

*Resolution/overscan issue for text*

If `fsck` kicks in or there is some error, text is not aligned with the screen. There are large overlaps on at least left, top and bottom making it almost unusable. Ctrl-Alt-F1 after boot displays the console correctly.